# I am getting error "Missing \endcsname inserted." while compiling a latex document

Tags: compiling, rmarkdown

I am trying to create an R Markdown template package so that I can prepare reports repeatedly in a consistent format. I prepared the R Markdown file, and the Latex file as well. I can compile the Latex file in TeXStudio without any error. However, when I attempt to compile the same file from within RStudio, I am getting errors. The Latex code is as follows.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
%Preamble
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{authblk}
\bibliography{references.bib}
\usepackage{booktabs}%for long tables
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\usepackage[a4paper=true,xetex]{hyperref}
\else
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\fi
\usepackage{lipsum}%to add random sentences
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{totpages}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{references.bib}
\hypersetup{
    unicode=false,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
    pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat’s toolbar?
    pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat’s menu?
    pdffitwindow=true,      % window fit to page when opened
    pdfstartview={FitH},    % fits the width of the page to the window
    pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new window
    colorlinks=true,        % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=black,        % color of internal links (change box color with linkbordercolor)
    citecolor=black,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=red,          % color of file links
    urlcolor=black          % color of external links
}
\begin{document}
\title{A Sample Title}

\date{\today}
% Title Page


\begin{titlepage}
    \newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}



    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   TITLE SECTION
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \makeatletter
    \HRule \\[0.4cm]
    \center
    { \huge \bfseries Sample Title}\\[0.4cm] % Title of your document
    \HRule \\[1.5cm]

    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \textsc{\LARGE Sales Report}\\[1.5cm] %Type of project
    \textsc{\Large Author 1}\\[0.5cm]
    \textsc{\Large Author 2}\\[0.5cm]
    \textsc{\Large Author 3}\\[0.5cm]
    % Name of your organization
    \textsc{\Large ABC Company}\\[0.5cm] % Major heading such as course name
    \textsc{\large Quarterly Sales Report}\\[0.5cm] % Minor heading such as course title
\end{titlepage}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

When I compile it in TeXStudio (using tinytex), there is no error. The process exits normally. I have also kept the references.bib file in the working directory. But when I use RStudio Knit button to compile the same TeX file, I get following error:

```
tlmgr search --file --global "/biblatex-dm.cfg"
tlmgr search --file --global "/nil.lbx"
tlmgr search --file --global "/skeleton.bbl"
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \def 
l.46 \newpage

Error: LaTeX failed to compile skeleton.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See skeleton.log for more info.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In parse_packages(logfile, quiet = !verbose) :
  Failed to find a package that contains biblatex-dm.cfg
2: In parse_packages(logfile, quiet = !verbose) :
  Failed to find a package that contains nil.lbx
3: In parse_packages(logfile, quiet = !verbose) :
  Failed to find a package that contains skeleton.bbl
Execution halted
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: compare the log-files of the two compilations.

Answer (score 1):

Next to the knitr button you have a setting wheel > output options > output format : PDF > advanced > keep .tex files

so you can investigate on the .tex file itself, and pinpoint the LaTeX issue, because the error message tells you it's on line 46

(i just lost an hour trying to figure out why i couldn't use python's matplotlib in Rmarkdown because i used `knitr::opts_chunk$set(out.width = "80%")` which is translated to `0,8\linewidth` in the .tex file instead of `0.8\linewidth`..)